# Downsides of Extending a USB Bluetooth Antenna?

Tags: usb, antenna, bluetooth, interference

I found an interesting video about how to extend the range on a USB Bluetooth antenna by resoldering a new antenna in its place: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwKWOdOHiWY).

I'm planning on using a Bluetooth enabled portable EEG as a input device for an arts display in a few months, and I'm somewhat concerned about interference from the audience's Bluetooth enabled phones.

The performer wants to be able to walk around the audience as a part of the performance, which might be about 20m from the stage where the computuer will be located.

What are the potential downsides of this approach? Is the extension antenna more prone to interference? Is it a good application for this kind of project? Is it better to have the extended antenna mounted on the ceiling near the center of the room?

Comment: More gain = smaller coverage angle.  That higher gain antenna is still omni directional so tends to not radiate well at higher or lower angles to the horizontal plane (probably). So mounting it on ABOUT the same horizontal level as the performer (somewhat higher OK) is probably best. Impedance of aerial sMAY vary depending on design so match to system may be OK or not. Trying it is best check :-) :-(. Don't pay too much - there are many similar.

Comment: Rather than messing up the antenna, I'd just use a BT4.0 class 1 USB dongle and a long USB extension cable. Mounting the dongle high up in the air, one can maintain line-of-sight even when mingling among viewers. For 20m  bleutooth to work somewhat reliably (and within FCC specs), you need line-of-sight.